# getting text from dynamiclly created texbox

Tags: c#, winforms, dynamic, textbox

I'm trying to  make windows app to calculate GPA . the user can enter the number of subjects and the app create textboxes as many as the number of subjects . but i can't get the values from textboxes . and this is the code I'm trying

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(textBox1.Text); i++)
        {
            Label supjects = new Label();
            supjects.Text = "supject " + (i+1) ;
            supjects.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(60, 70+i*41);
            supjects.Name = "supject" + i;
            this.Controls.Add(supjects);

            TextBox fullMark = new TextBox();
            fullMark.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(162, 70 + i * 41);
            fullMark.Size=new System.Drawing.Size(57, 24);
            fullMark.Name = "fullMark" + i;
            this.Controls.Add(fullMark);

            TextBox yourMark = new TextBox();
            yourMark.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(272, 70 + i * 41);
            yourMark.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(57, 24);
            yourMark.Name = "yourMark" + i;
            this.Controls.Add(yourMark);


        }
```

Comment: thank you , but can you send me code to that ? @L.B

Answer (score 0):

Declare a dictionary like

```
Dictionary<string, TextBox> textBoxes = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>();
```

And add your textboxes in the loop to it.

```
 textBoxes.Add("yourMark" + i, yourMark);
```

Now you can use it like

```
var text = textBoxes["yourMark2"].Text
```

Comment: can you declear what is (yourMark) in this line
textBoxes.Add("yourMark" + i, yourMark);

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(textBox1.Text); i++)
    {
        Label l = this.Controls.Find("supject" + i,true)[0] as Label;
        l.Text = "yes";
        //whatever
     }
```

to find YourMark, it's
    Label l = this.Controls.Find("YourMark",true)[0] as Label;